# Display multiline in Repeater Control?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010

I am creating a Facebook Wall like structure and used repeater control for that using C#-Visual Studio 2010 amd Sql Server 2005 as database.

I am unable to display multiline text in repeater control

Script

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="100%" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:Repeater ID="myrepeater" runat="server">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <table width="100%" style="font: 8pt verdana">
                    <tr style="background-color:#3C78C3">
                        <th>SCRAPS</th>
                    </tr>

            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                       <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.scraps") %>
                    </td>
               </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                </table>
            </FooterTemplate>
```

So, When I click on submit button, text stores in `DataItem.scraps` (which is column in my database table) and displays in repeater control.

But when I am inputting multiline Text in Textbox, it is displayed singleline in repeater control.

I want it to be displayed multiline repeater control.

So what is the problem exactly
1) Is it storing singleline text in database
2) or, repeater control problem

And, how to resolve it?

Please help me.

Thanks in advance, 
Nikhil

Comment: Multiline what? Multiline text box? Multiple items in the repeater?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The repeater control is pretty straight forward.  There is no reason you can't control your output very thoroughly, just put everything in your item template:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptWall" runat="server">  
<HeaderTemplate>
    <h1>The wall<h1>
</HeaderTemplate>  
<ItemTemplate>
    <hr>
    <asp:TextBox id="txtPost" runat="server" textmode="multiline" text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Posttext")%>'></asp:TextBox>
    <hr>
</ItemTemplate>  
<FooterTemplate>  
    <h3>put stuff here to add post</h3>
</FooterTemplate>  
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Since you used a multiline textbox to save the initial data, use a multiline textbox again when you display it.  Just make the control read only.  The web does NOT show line breaks, so that is why you're seeing only one line.  Putting your data in a multiline textbox should solve that.  If it doesn't, then you will need to encode your data before it is saved to change all the linebreaks to "<br />"